# rg.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException when I have 2 different jdbc jars on classpath

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, command-line, groovy, classpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manifest.MF issue with MSSQLSERVER 2008 and Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311992/manifest-mf-issue-with-mssqlserver-2008-and-groovy)

I have a very simple groovy script with 2 database connections:

1. One db connection to Oracle
2. Another db connection to SQLServer

**Problem**

When I run the program through the GGTS Editor (The groovy and grails version of SpringSource Tool Suite), the two queries run and return results fine. But, when I run the program from the command line, from the project folder as follows:

```
groovy -cp lib\jtds-1.3.0.jar lib\ojdbc6-11g.jar src\Starter.groovy
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\workspace-ggts\Test>groovy -cp lib\jtds-1.3.0.jar lib\ojdbc6-11g.jar src\Star
ter.groovy
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\workspace-ggts\Test\lib\ojdbc6-11g.jar: 1: unexpected char: 0x3 @ line 1, col
umn 3.
   PK♥ ßî∟9              ♦ META-INF/■╩  ♥     ☻       PK♥♦ ßî∟9            ¶   M
ETA-INF/MANIFEST.MF?æ┴N├0►D∩æ≥☼½₧α►7)R[rúΘÑá☻R½^æq6─òcç╡SΦ▀π4◄ →        ─╒3;π}╗µ
Z▬h]┤C▓╥Φ¶↕▬ç┴¬¬§V¿↔w■╤ï:7ö┬♥qí►2C╡íôtf▌Jº0♣│╧ƒ┼öφ9
     ^

1 error
```

**What I have Tried**

1. I have tried using the jtds driver to connect to SQLServer as I thought the problem was the sqljdbc4.jar from Microsoft site [based on this same problem reported differently here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311992/manifest-mf-issue-with-mssqlserver-2008-and-groovy)
2. I have tried putting semicolons to separate the classpath dependencies, and still same error.
3. I have upgraded java version to 1.7.  Groovy version is 2.0.5
4. From the IDE it runs fine, but from command line I get the error.
5. If I comment out one of the db access code (connection, query, println of resultset) leaving my groovy script with only one db connection & access the program runs fine from command line. For example:

This

```
groovy -cp lib\jtds-1.3.0.jar src\Starter.groovy
```

or this:

```
groovy -cp lib\ojdbc6-11g.jar src\Starter.groovy
```

does work. As soon as I add the code and the jar in the classpath for that second db access I get the error reported above.

I am out of thoughts or ideas

Comment: Is not a duplicate the problem I'm having is the same but I am wording it differently.  If you read this question you will see that I mentioned my other question. This is a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in your classpath need to be separated with a semi-colon on Windows.  On unix-like platforms like Linux or OSX, the separator is a colon.  Groovy is treating the second jar file as the script, and the script name as the first command line parameter.

Try this:

```
groovy -cp lib\jtds-1.3.0.jar;lib\ojdbc6-11g.jar src\Starter.groovy
```

Do you get a different error with that?

Comment: I told them that when they asked this before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311992/manifest-mf-issue-with-mssqlserver-2008-and-groovy apparently,  despite what they said, they didn't listen

Comment: @ataylor even when separating with semicolons I still get the same EXACT ERROR.  Tim Yates I do not know what your issue is.  I do listen, be part of the solution rather than negative.

Comment: It worked!!! Apparently, when I put the semicolon I left a space like this: **lib\jtds-1.3.0.jar; lib\ojdbc6-11g.jar** instead of doing this **lib\jtds-1.3.0.jar;lib\ojdbc6-11g.jar**
Thanks ataylor and thanks tim_yates as well